# Enforce concurrent modification of a variable (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, googletest

I'm trying to unit test an atomic library (I am aware that an atomic library is not suitable for unit testing, but I still want to give it a try)

For this, I want to let X parallel threads increment a counter and evaluate the resulting value (it should be X).

The code is below. The problem is that is it never breaks. The `Counter` always nicely ends up being 2000 (see below). What I also notice is that the `cout` is also printed as a whole (instead of being mingled, what I remember seeing with other multithreaded `couts`)

My question is: why doesn't this break? Or how can I let this break?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool start = false;

int Counter = 0;

void Inc() {

    // Wait until test says start
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [] {return start; });

    std::cout << "Incrementing in thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    Counter++;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(Inc));
    }

    // signal the threads to start
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    // Now check whether value is right
    std::cout << "Counter: " << Counter << std::endl;
}
```

The results looks like this (but then 2000 lines)

```
Incrementing in thread 130960
Incrementing in thread 130948
Incrementing in thread 130944
Incrementing in thread 130932
Incrementing in thread 130928
Incrementing in thread 130916
Incrementing in thread 130912
Incrementing in thread 130900
Incrementing in thread 130896
Counter: 2000
```

Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE: Reducing the nr of threads to 4, but incrementing a million times in a for loop (as suggested by @tkausl) the `cout` of thread id appear to be sequential..

UPDATE2: Turns out that the lock had to be unlocked to prevent exclusive access per thread (`lk.unlock()`). An additional `yield` in the for-loop increased the race condition effect.

Comment: Too many threads which do too little. Try with two or four threads which each increment the variable one million times in a loop.

Comment: You are trying to produce an heisenbug. There is no 100% way.

Comment: @tkausl Tnx, see update

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f0b8c68851694c6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv.wait(lk, [] {return start; });` only returns with the `lk` acquired. So it's exclusive. You might want to unlock `lk` right after:

```
void Inc() {
    // Wait until test says start
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [] {return start; });
    lk.unlock();

    Counter++;
}
```

And you must remove `std::cout`, because it potentially introduces synchronization.

Comment: the ``couts`` seem to mix after a while. Haven't seen an inconsistent counter though.

Comment: @Ben On my computer(E5-1620), it gives ~1999, but mostly 2000.

Comment: Adding a sleep to the for-loop (see update) helps. It's now finally not working :)